# Will instance objects in multiple threads have access to the same static class and variables?

Tags: java, constructor, static

If in my Main class I create an object like this: `Tools tool = new Tools()` and inside the `Tools`constructor I do this:

```
Web web;
public Tools(){
    web = new Web();
}
```

Will every thread's `tools` object reference the same web? I need them all to have a reference to a different `Web`. Web is a static class that performs operations using a web driver which is why I need them all to be separate.

Comment: Every instance of Tools has its own instance of Web. Are different threads using the same instance of Tools?

Comment: Yeah ever instance of tools has its own Web or should. And no every thread has a `new Tools()`

Comment: If every thread makes a `new Tools`, then the threads are *not* sharing instances of `Web`.

Comment: this is the case even if web and all variables are static in the web class?

Comment: In the code you've posted, `web` is an instance field, not a static field. I can't say how code I haven't seen would work. However, if all the fields in `Web` are static, it may be irrelevant how many instances of `Web` you have, and you would have to rewrite it to make it thread safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will every thread's tools object reference the same web?

All threads will have access to the same reference (provided they all have access to the same instance of `Tools`), but they won't necessarily see the same value, because of visibility in terms of the memory model.

They would see the same value if you declared the `web` member `final`.

> I need them all to have a reference to a different `Web`

In that case you'd need to use a [`ThreadLocal<Web>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html).

```
ThreadLocal<Web> web = ThreadLocal.withInitial(Web::new);
```

Comment: this will make it so that every thread has its own instance of web?

Comment: +1'd for `ThreadLocal`, but might be worth adding a note on 'if they _don't_ all have access to the same `Tools` instance'.

Comment: According to the OP's comments, every thread makes its own instance of Tools. So there doesn't seem to be any need for ThreadLocal.

Comment: @khelwood indeed. That comment was added after I answered.